# How To I Share A Programming Technique?

Tags: vb.net

I have developed (with vb2010) a technique to add several bullet styles to a Rich Text Box in addition to the built-in Dot Bullet. The technique is available to anyone who needs that capability at no cost.  I am just interested in giving it to anyone to help in their programming. So my question is how best to make people aware of this package.  I have a example demo for anyone who is interested.

Have searched the internet but have not found an answer to my question.

Comment: Could put it somewhere like [GitHub](https://github.com), [Sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net), or some other related site. Then tag the addition with vb and other relevant tags to attract the intended audience.

Comment: Thanks Paul. I'll give them a try.